# Django: preserving GET parameters in URL template tag

Tags: python, django

I'm using a GET parameter in my Django app to pass in information, that I want to be preserved in future links using Django's [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag.

In my case, this is to allow view-only access within the app.

Example URL:

`https://my.app/entry/123?key=abcdef`

An example link on that page is already created like this:

`<a href="{% url 'entry_detail' entry.id %}">View more details</a>`

**Desired result:**

I would like Django's URL template tag to automatically preserve any GET parameters named `key` throughout the app. In this case, it would generate new URLs with that same parameter applied. For example:

`https://my.app/entry/123/details?key=abcdef`

**Workarounds**

[This blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/benbacardi/d6cd0fb8c85e1547c3c60f95f5b2d5e1) solve the problem by creating a new template tag and using that instead of Django's `url` template tag.

Is that really the best solution? I'd end up having to replace every instance of `{% url %}` throughout my app with my own tag. It also wouldn't fix the use of [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Answer (score 2):

Django middlewares may work for what you want. You could check when you receive the key parameter and store in [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/), then if there is not key parameter in the url append it :

```
class DetectKeyParameter:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
         

@staticmethod
def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs): 
    return view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)


def __call__(self, request):
    if 'key' in request.GET:
        #If alerady is on the url just store it on session
        request.session['key'] = request.GET.get('key')
    else:
        if 'key' in request.session:         
            if not request.GET._mutable:
                #You need to change this property to add parameters to GET
                request.GET._mutable = True

                # now you can edit it
                request.GET['key'] = request.session['key']         
                request.GET._mutable = False
       
    response = self.get_response(request)        
    return response
```

This way, you'll have the key parameter on every request, until you delete the session variable. Perhaps the code doesn't work 100%, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't actually re-write links on the page, but I appreciate that you worked around that by moving `key` to a session variable. The downside of this approach is that these pages can't be shared or bookmarked.

Comment: You right! Maybe, instead of adding the key to the request, you can try redirecting directly adding the parameter to the url `return redirect(request.url+'?key='request.GET.get('key'))`.

Comment: That ended up creating a redirect loop. It also feels a bit kludgy as it wouldn't honor existing GET parameters. The last framework I worked with handled all of this automatically so I'm a bit suprised it isn't included with Django. Thanks anyway!